# MPV player won't quit

Tags: 17.10, mpv-media-player

In Ubuntu 17.10, MPV runs fine, but I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> or *right-click* → *Quit* from the dock. I have been manually opening System Monitor and selecting *End Process*.

Is this a known bug? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

Just press <kbd>q</kbd> if you want to close the player or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to close the player and have it remember the current position.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Why is it different from every other window/application in the OS?

Comment: The global shortcut to close programs in Ubuntu is "Alt+F4".  Some programs also provide "Ctrl+q" as a shortcut, but not all. MPV has its own shortcuts and its developers have chosen just pressing "q" to quit. You can change that if you want by adding `Ctrl+q` in `~/.config/mpv/input.conf`.

Answer (score 6):

No, that's normal, you can quit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. And change options in config file.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Why is it different from every other window/application in the OS?